# Scroll window halfway between zt and zz in Vim

Tags: vim, scroll

I often find myself wanting to scroll a Vim window so that the line I'm on is roughly a quarter of the screen down—it provides more room to breathe than <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, but has more code displayed than <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>.  It's also helpful when my cursor is at the start of a function I want to read, but <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> will cut off the Javadoc-like comments.

Is there some magic I can use to do this?  I'm afraid I don't understand Vim's scripting at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps `set scrolloff=5` (or how many lines above and below the cursor you would like) will do the trick for you.  It isn't exactly what you asked for, but close enough?

Comment: For those unfamiliar with `scrolloff`, it effectively prevents your cursor from going within the top or bottom `x` lines of the screen by scrolling.  So, you start scrolling when the cursor hits `x` lines from the top of the screen, rather than the top.  This is incidentally behavior I'd like, so I'm satisfied with this solution.

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
nnoremap <expr> zT 'zt' . winheight(0)/4 . '<c-y>'
nnoremap <expr> zB 'zb' . winheight(0)/4 . '<c-e>'
```

which will remap zT to zt followed by the quarter of current window height and CTRL-Y (which scrolls one line up, leaving cursor where it is).

Comment: This is more accurately what I asked for, but the combination of commands produces an unpleasant jerky motion.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov I think you might get rid of that if you `set lazyredraw`